# What does mean "authority" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"These honourable Accessories [supporters] of the Heraldic Shield are said to have been introduced, (like Quartering) by Edward III, but they are of uncertain *authority* until the reign of Henry VI." (Boutell, Charles., A Manual of Heraldry, p123)

What does mean "authority" in the above sentence?
At first, I thought it alludes to citations of references but it is meaningless in historical point of view. is it possible it means importance in there?

There is another similar sentence:

"A lion and an antelope, and sometimes an antelope and a swan, have been assigned to Henry IV. and Henry V., but upon no very reliable *authority*." (Clark, Hugh., An Introduction to Heraldry, p67)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context `uncertain authority` and `no very reliable authority` mean that the source of the information is not credible (AKA "not authoritative"), and thus the information should be taken as hearsay rather than fact.